# Java: my .jar file created, but the main class cannot be found?

Tags: java, class, jar, path, manifest

I've got these following steps:

(1) I'm under my Linux home directory of /home/a

(2) A simple java file, cat m.java

```
 package my;
 public class m{
     public static void main(String[] args){
     }
 }
```

(3) javac m.java

(4) mkdir my && cp m.class my/

(5) $ cat manifest.mf

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: my/m
Class-Path: /home/a
```

(6)  jar cfm m.jar manifest.mf m.class

(7) java -jar m.jar

```
Error: Could not find or load main class m.class
```

How to make it work?

Comment: Just curious why you compile and _then_ copy the .class file into the package directory? Why not just have the source code in the `my` directory to start? Also, according this example the `Main-Class` attribute uses dot notation for identifying the main class: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Main-Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html) should be with package with dot separated and not `/`

```
Main-Class: my.m
```

> Main-Class: MyPackage.MyClass

Remove [Class-Path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html) line if you don't need more jars

> Adding Classes to the JAR File's Classpath
>   You may need to reference classes in other JAR files from within a JAR file.

Answer (score 0):

You need create manifest.txt file giving class package name as,

```
Main-Class: MyPackage.MyClass
```